# how much extra Space/RAM/CPU is used by apache solr?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am using MySQL database for my webapp.
I need to search over multiple tables & multiple columns, it very similar like full text searching inside those columns.

I need know your experience of using any Full Text Search API (eg. solr/lucene/mapReduce/hadoop etc..) over using simple SQL in terms of :

1. Speed performance
2. **Extra space usage**
3. **Extra CPU usage** (is it continuously building index? )
4. How long it takes to build index or it get ready for use?
5. Please let me know your experience of using these frameworks.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: @Rosdi but i think, this question has an impact on application design and the tools and frameworks you use to create your application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your questions

1.) i have an database with round about 5 Million Docs. MySQL Fulltextsearch needs 2-3 Minutes. Solr/Lucene needs for the same search round about 200-400 milliseconds.

2.) The space you need depends on your configuration, the number of copyfields and if you store the data or if you only index the data. In my configuration, full DB is indexed, but only metadata is sored. So an 30GB DB needs 40 GB on for Solr/Lucene. Keep in mind, that if you like to (re)optimize your index, you need temporary 100% of the index-size again.

3.) If you migrate from MySQL fulltext-Index to Lucene/Solr, you save CPU Power. Using MySQL Fulltext needs much more CPU Power than Solr Fulltext search -> look at answer 1.)

4.) depends on the number of documents, the size of the documents and the disk-speed. Of course the CPU performance is very important. There is not a good scaling over multiple CPU's during index-time. 2 big cores are much more faster than 8 small cores.
Indexing 5 Million Docs (44GB) in my environment needs 2-3 hours on an dual core VM ware server.

5.) Migrating from MySQL Fulltext-Index to Lucene/Solr Fulltextindex was the best idea ever. ;-) But probably you have to redesign your application.

//Edit to answer the question "Will the Lucene Index get updated immediately after some Insert statements "

It depends on your SOlR configuration, but it is possible

Answer (score 3):

Q1: Lucene is usually faster and more powerful in terms of features (if correctly implemented)

Q2: if you don't store the original content, it's usually 20-30% of the original (indexed) content

Q4: Depends on the size of your content that you want to index, on the amount of processing you'll be doing (you can have your own analyzers, etc), then your hardware... you'll have to do a benchmark. For one of my projects, last time it took 15min to build a 500MB index (out of the box performance, no tweaks attempted), for another, it took 3 days to build a huge 17GB index.

Comment: thanks for the reply, In my project, basically user is supposed to upload zip/tar file and it'll parsed and so many records will get entered in DB so my question is Will the Lucene Index get updated immediately after some Insert statements or do we need to explicitly trigger lucene to rebuild index, i mean Is the indexing happen realtime?

Comment: Lucene is a free text search library, that's all, it doesn't know anything about relational databases, messaging systems, whatever you may have. You'll be using the API to send content for indexing and later for searching.